# Angularjs date format issue showing AM instead of PM

Tags: angularjs

I'm converting from a UTC to local time using angular:

```
{{item.created | date:"medium": 'UTC'}}
```

The filter is showing AM instead of PM when the hours are after midday, and vice versa.

e.g

Converting **2016-11-07 23:57:16 (UTC)**    to local gives me **Nov 8, 2016 5:57:16 AM**; when it should be **Nov 8, 2016 5:57:16 PM**

Any idea of what could be wrong, or what should I check in order to fix this?

Comment: what is your local time zone?

Comment: Passing a *timezone* parameter formats the date for that timezone so you aren't showing it as local time

Comment: @DanielA.White CST

Answer (score 1):

As @Phil stated in the comments to your question, the *timezone* parameter is used to convert it to the timezone you have specified. Given that your output time displays as 6 hours ahead of the input time, this means your input time is in CST (-0600) and it is displaying as UTC (+0000).

If the input time is actually the UTC time but your JavaScript believes that it is in local time (CST in this case) then you will need to modify the time in your javascript to be the actual time.

You can do this with the following:

```
item.created.setMinutes(item.created.getMinutes() - item.created.getTimezoneOffset());
```

This will subtract the current timezone offset (in minutes) to the time thus making it local time in the local timezone instead of UTC in the local timezone. Then you can display it as a normal date:

```
{{item.created | date:"medium"}}
```